# WebUSB will not connect because another device is using the same interface

Tags: javascript, linux, usb, linux-mint, webusb

So I'm trying to connect to openEEG upon running the `claimInterface()` function I get

> NetworkError: Unable to claim interface

lsusb shows this problem is likely because some MSI driver is running on the same driver

**Output of  lsusb -v -s4**

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1770:ff00  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x1770 
  idProduct          0xff00 
  bcdDevice            1.10
  iManufacturer           1 MSI EPF USB
  iProduct                1 MSI EPF USB
  iSerial                 1 MSI EPF USB
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           34
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode           33 US
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      57
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
Device Status:     0xa630
  (Bus Powered)

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x0403 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
  idProduct          0x6001 FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
  bcdDevice            6.00
  iManufacturer           1 FTDI
  iProduct                2 FT232R USB UART
  iSerial                 3 A105XV9J
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               90mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2 FT232R USB UART
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

I originally tried adding 255 as the classCode on `navigator.usb.requestDevice` because the documentation said I can do that, but they don't have the same IDs so that was pointless. Also upon reconnecting I can only get `lsusb` to output of the MSI driver even though Chrome picks it up and I got an  `access denied error`.

which is strange because I changed the udev rules and used `sudo chmod -R 777 *` In     `dev/bus/usb`

I then found in folder "001" a file that I previously had to manually change the permissions of thinking it was the MSI driver but this time the original file was deleted in place of one named "007" instead of "005" (probably because I tried plugging the device in twice)

So this must be a combination of MSI security features? and OpenEEG creating a new file every time it's loaded?

The only solution I can think of is to delete a file that I don't understand and change the permissions every time it's plugged in. both of which are very prohibitive for uses especially since I want my website to work across a broad range of devices and operating systems

PS: Using Linux Mint if that's relevant and here is my code(I don't think it's the problem) that is being run with on local node.js server

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
  let button = document.getElementById('connect')

  button.addEventListener('click', async() => {
    var device
    const VENDOR_ID = 0x0403
    const PRODUCT_ID = 0x6001
    const CLASS_CODE = 255


      device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({
        filters: [{
          vendorId: VENDOR_ID,
          productId: PRODUCT_ID,
          classCode: CLASS_CODE
        }]
      })

      console.log('opening..')
      await device.open()
      console.log('open!')
      .then(() => device.selectConfiguration(1))
      .then(() => device.claimInterface(0)).catch(error => { console.log(error + 'eeeeeeerrrr ' + device.configuration.interfaces[0].interfaceNumber); });


      console.log(device);
      await device.close().catch(error => { console.log(error + 'eeeeeeerrrr'); });
});


  })
```

EDIT/UPDATE: lsusb returns nothing when not connected the two drivers are coming from the same input???????

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your device on the USB port Linux loads its driver and claim the device for itself.

If you want to use it somewhere else just unload the driver:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r ftdi_sio
```

If you reboot your computer the driver will load again and you'll have to unload it manually. If you want to keep it unloaded you can do:

```
$ echo "ftdi_sio" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

I can understand why it got you confused, considering the output of `lsusb` is not that clear but I think the other MSI driver is for the root USB controller on your computer. If you remove it you won't be able to see your ports or anything connected to them.

If unloading the driver does not fix your problem maybe you're not claiming the correct device. You can find out more reading the log file if you write on your navigation bar `chrome://device-log/`